# Regex to find any tag inside curly braces in a string

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am struggling to find out which regex could I use to clean up this string:

```
{1}WH{/1}{2}A{/2}{3}T{/3}{4} {/4}{5}I{/5}{6}T{/6}{7} {/7}{8}I{/8}{9}S{/9}
```

So that I read only the text?

thanks a lot,

M

Comment: so what would be the substring that you want to pull from that?

Comment: "WHAT IT IS" - I would like to remove all tags between curly braces

Answer (score 2):

You can use string replace:

```
import re
line = "{1}WH{/1}{2}A{/2}{3}T{/3}{4} {/4}{5}I{/5}{6}T{/6}{7} {/7}{8}I{/8}{9}S{/9}"
line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z\s]", "", line) 
print(line)# WHAT IT IS
```

Where:

[^a-zA-Z\s] -> Catch all char other than alphabets and whiteSpace

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YioUF5/1

Comment: Thanks a lot - sorry about the basic question :) what if I wanted to explicitly filter the tags {}, I.e., if there were numbers and special characters in the text?